# Nexus 7 is not booting up after android marshmallow update

Tags: nexus-7, boot, 6.0-marshmallow

I received OTA for my nexus 7 tablet few days back and since then my device is not booting up. Can someone please help how to get it working ?

Comment: A few questions about your issue: Did your device stop booting immediately after installing the OTA or several days after?

Also, is your device stuck on the boot animation or do you just get a blank display?

Finally, is your Nexus 7 a 2012 or 2013 model?

Comment: @LJD200 it's 2013 device and it stopped after update installation. I forgot to charge after update and once it shut down, it never booted again.

Answer (score 1):

Download the `Nexus Root Toolkit` from [here](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/).  It has options to restore any Nexus device back to its factory settings, including bricked or boot looping devices, under the `Flash Stock + Unroot` button.  You should select the option `Current status` of `Soft-Bricked / Bootloop`.  The toolkit will walk you through, step by step, restoring your Nexus to working condition.

You may lose any data stored on the device.

[image: Nexus Root Toolkit screenshot]

Comment: This should certainly work but solutions such as clearing the cache and/or data partition may be more desirable as first steps since they do not result in data loss...

Comment: That's certainly worth a try, but that's harder for a newbie to do, especially if they haven't installed a custom recovery.  Based on what the OP said about the battery dying in the middle of an update, I'm willing to bet that the the system or boot partition was only partially written and is corrupted though.  Bigger guns are needed to fix that.

Comment: You can wipe these from the stock recovery. The OP says that the device ran out of battery after the update. I agree that flashing stock will almost certainly fix the update but I think it's worth trying some other things before building up to this if they don't work.

Comment: You should add an answer then, I wasn't aware they stock recovery key you do that, others may not either.

Answer (score 0):

Bradley Uffner's answer is very good but try the following first and then follow his advice if these solutions fail.

1. Boot into stock recovery (guide [here](http://www.robschmuecker.com/how-to-boot-into-recovery-mode-nexus-7/)) and wipe the cache partition then reboot.
2. If that fails, boot into recovery in the same way and wipe the data partition.

Comment: With power and volume button also my tables is not coming up. It doesn't load recovery screen also.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you can't access the bootloader so please try again and report back. When the device is turned off, press the Power and Volume Down Keys together until the Android symbol appears (this should take around 5 seconds to appear but hold for more like 10 if it doesn't appear at first). If this doesn't work then this issue may not be fixable and certainly not easily. It's not really possible that running out of battery while Android is running could cause an issue involving loss of bootloader access. Hope we can sort out this issue!